# How to change variable value in a function

Tags: python

I have tried to do send variable and change its value in function. But, I have not succesful. What I have done;

```
>>>a = True

>>>def f (c):
       c = False

>>>f(a)
>>>a
a = True
```

But I want a to be False, without using return, can I do ?

Comment: Do you have capital `C` passed to the function and lowercase `c` inside the function in the code you tested?

Comment: @jonhopkins even if he didn't, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I actually wasn't sure if it would, but I figured I would still point that out, because it would affect stuff later on if the poster doesn't know about case-sensitivity..

Comment: Short answer: it can't be done, at least for simple types as given in the example.

Comment: Medium-length answer: Variables in Python are references. Assignment statements *change the reference*. So when you write `c = false`, you're not changing the value of what `c` *used to* point to; you're changing *what c points to*. You are *not* changing what `a` points to. (I recommend reading the top answer to the "How do I pass a variable by reference" question, though.)